# (Using Eclipse) Unresolved compilation errors: GradeBook cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I'm following along the textbook, "Java: How to Program," and using Eclipse. I've written the worked out example as it appears in the textbook, but I'm getting this error: Unresolved Compilation problems: GradeBook cannot be resolved to a type

Similar questions have suggested that I import the GradeBook.java class as a package, but the textbook example doesn't do that, and I don't know how. Why would I need to do it if it worked without an import in the textbook? They've also suggested that I fix the errors shown in the Problems View, which displays the exact same errors as the console (and therefore didn't help me troubleshoot further). Also, if you have any tips/resources for someone jumping into Java, please let me know!

There are two files: GradeBook.java and GradeBookTest.java

```java
//Fig 3.11 GradeBook.java
public class GradeBook 
{

    private String courseName; //initialized local var for any object of class "gradebook"

    public GradeBook(String name)  //create object with parameter
    { 
        courseName = name;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String name) {
        courseName = name; // change name from one used to create instance of GradeBook
    }

    public String getCourseName() 
    {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.printf("Welcome to gradebook for %s\n", getCourseName());
    }

}
```

[Second Script]

```java
//Fig 3.2 Gradebook Test
// Create GradeBook object, pass string taken from input and
// print message
public class GradeBookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // created GB object with parameter (passed to class file's constructor code)
        // constructor used to specify course's name (need some initial course to create a GB for!)
        GradeBook myGB1 = new GradeBook("CSC 171");
        GradeBook myGB2 = new GradeBook("CSC 172");

        //display initial "courseName" variable's value for both instances
        System.out.printf("Course Name: %s\n", myGB1.getCourseName() );
        System.out.printf("Course Name: %s\n", myGB2.getCourseName() );
    } // end of main

} // end class GradeBookTest
```

The output should simply print the statements in GradeBookTest

Comment: How are you running GradeBookTest, and how are you telling it where to find GradeBook.class?

Comment: Hello, your code is fine, you need to build your project before running your `main` and check if the two files are in the same package then it's okay otherwise you need to `import GradeBook`

Comment: in which directory are these files? What are your project settings regarding Java Build Path?

Comment: Are both the `GradeBook.java` and `GradeBookTest.java` in a source folder of the same Java Project? Are they both in the same package?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thank you, good to know, Eclipse is not a close a friend  ...

Comment: @Aaron I've got two separate projects (therefore two separate src folders: GradeBook/src and GradeBookTest/src). Is it possible to two classes/java files under the same project? I thought every Java file had to be its own project

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I have two separate Java projects in the eclipse-workspace directory: GradeBook and GradeBookTest

Comment: No, projects are expected to contain many source files, you can't do much OOP if you can only define a single class. You should definitely move the GradeBookTest.java file to the GradeBook project. That was your problem : the GradeBookTest class didn't have access to the GradeBook class definition it referred to and couldn't be compiled without it

Comment: if ou really want this in distinct projects you must include the GradeBook one in the settings of the other one. But the usual way is to put all related classes/sources in the same project, as Aaron already explained - much more *natural* and easier (and sure possible - no reason to have only one file in a directory)

Comment: @Aaron Hi Aaron, I'd like to accept your answer, but I don't see a check mark anywhere (the FAQ said there should be one) . Do you know how I can accept your answer? I just clicked the GradeBook project, then File>New>Class, and re-created the GradeBookTest file inside the GradeBook project. Thank you!

Comment: That's because those aren't answers (which your question has none of) but merely comments which can't be accepted. I'm searching whether there is a proper duplicate of this question in which case I'll close it, otherwise I might post an answer you could accept. What matters most is that your problem was resolved :)